Alternate proof to the Extreme Value Theorem
I'm following Spivak's Calculus and was revisiting some of my notes when I think I found a much more straightforward proof for the Extreme Value Theorem, compared to the one given in the book. I was wondering if it was correct. In fact, I've asked a similar question here, but the proof I suggested there was superfluous and, more importantly, incorrect.
Here's the formal theorem: "If $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ there exists an $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $\forall x\in[a,b], f(x_0)\geq f(x)$".
Proof:
First, let $A = \{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$. Now, by the boundedness theorem, $A$ has an upper bound. Therefore, $A$ has a supremum. Let $sup(A) = \alpha$. Suppose that $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha\neq f(x)$. Since $\alpha$ is an upper bound, $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha\geq f(x)$. Combining these two observations, $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha > f(x)$. Thus, $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha -f(x) > 0$.

In other words, there is always a gap between $\alpha$ and the function, as indicated by the image above. This means that you can always find another number, $\alpha'$, which is smaller than $\alpha$ and also always has a gap to the function. This makes $\alpha'$ an upper bound that is smaller than $\alpha$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is the supremum.
To formally prove this intuition, we consider $B$:
$$B = \{\alpha - f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$$
Since $\alpha - f(x) > 0$, $0$ is a lower bound for $B$. This means that there exists an infimum of B, which we'll call $\beta$. Thus, $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha - f(x)\geq\beta$. Now, because $0$ is a lower bound for $B$, $\beta\geq 0$. However, $\beta\neq 0$. Suppose not. Suppose $\beta = 0$. Since $\alpha - f(x) > 0$, there exists a $c > 0$ such that $\alpha - f(x) > c$. So, $c$ is a lower bound that is bigger than $\beta$, contradicting the fact that $\beta$ is an infimum. So, $\beta > 0$.
This means that there exists $d > 0$ such that $\beta - d > 0$. Let $\alpha' = \alpha - d$ and $\beta' = \beta - d$. Now, $\alpha - f(x) \geq \beta\implies \alpha - d - f(x) \geq \beta - d\implies \alpha' - f(x)\geq\beta' > 0$.
Consider $y\in A$. $y = f(x)$ where $x\in[a,b]$. Thus, $\alpha' - f(x) > 0$. In other words, $\alpha' > f(x)$. So, $\alpha' > y$. So, $\forall y\in A, \alpha' > y$. But, $\alpha' < \alpha$. This contradicts the fact that $\alpha$ is the supremum. Hence, the original supposition that $\forall x\in[a,b], \alpha\neq f(x)$ is wrong. So, $\exists x_0\in[a,b]$ such that $\alpha = f(x_0)$. QED

"Since $ \alpha−f(x)>0$, there exists a $c>0$ such that $\alpha−f(x)>c$." How would you prove this assertion? The usual proof for this uses the extreme value theorem. so I suspect that your proof uses the theorem it wants to prove.

@alex440 no, the proof for this is quite simple. It follows from the fact that if $a > b$, there exists a $c > 0$ such that a - c > b. To prove this lemma is also easy. If $a > b$, then $a = b + k$ where $k > 0$. Now, let $0 < c < k$. Then, $j = k - c > 0$. So, $a - c = b + (k - c) = b + j$. Since $j > 0$, $a - c > b$.

What you are saying is true pointwise. It proves that for all $x$, there exists $c(x)$ (depends on $x$!) such that $\alpha - f(x) > c(x)$. The problem here is that want $c$ to not depend on $x$. Your argument gives a pointwise below bound while a uniform one is needed.

@alex440 actually I use the inequality $\alpha - f(x) > c_x$ only to show that $\beta > 0$. It's never used otherwise in my argument. I understand the problem you're talking about but not sure how my proof faces this problem.

If $c$ depends on $x$, it cannot be a lower bound (a lower bound doesn't depend on $x$) so your argument doesn't hold.

@alex440 Ah I see. But I'm guessing there has to be a way to prove that a uniform $c$ exists. After all, if we were to plot the graph $\alpha - f(x)$ it's an always positive function. Hence, it feels almost obvious that there exists a $c > 0$ such that $\alpha - f(x) > c$. It's like proving that $\forall x\in[a,b] g(x) > 0\implies g(x) > c$.

This is the hard part in the proof of extreme value theorem. Every argument that I can think about for the existence of such a $c$ is actually able to directly prove the extreme value theorem.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284867/proving-the-extreme-value-theorem
